# Android в PHP, кодировка

Tags: php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin, utf-8

Приложение android через PHP передает данные в базу данных. Но, вместо русских букв, отображаются вопросительные знаки. Добавил в пхп mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8"), но проблема не решилась. В базе везде utf8.
Еще момент, при проверке кода через google postman, данные отображаются корректно как в базе данных, так и в приложении..

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));


        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);
```

Comment: php код приёма данных тоже можно добавить.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда отправляешь через android приложение на php обработчик текст из кириллицы используй URLEncode, например отправка POST:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DataText", URLEncoder.encode(Text)));
```

Когда принимаешь эти данные в php обработчике достаешь их таким образом:

```
$DataText = urldecode($_POST['DataText']);
```